# Do we input only 1s for minterms and 0s for maxterms?

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression

This has been bugging me since a long time.

Suppose I have a boolean function F defined as follows:

[image]

Now, it can be expressed in its  SOP form as:

F = bar(X)Ybar(Z)+ XYZ

But I fail to understand why we always complement the 0s to express them as 1. Is it assumed that the inputs X, Y and Z will always be 1?
What is the practical application of that? All the youtube videos I watched on this topic, *how* to express a function in SOP form or as sum of minterms but *none* of them explained **why** we need this thing? Why do we need minterms in the first place?

As of now, I believe that we design circuits to yield and take only 1 and that's where minterms come in handy. But I couldn't get any confirmation of this thing anywhere so I am not sure I am right.

Maxterms are even more confusing. Do we design circuits that would yield and take only 0s? Is that the purpose of maxterms?

Answer (score 1):

> Why do we need minterms in the first place?

We do not need minterms, we need a way to solve a logic design problem, i.e. given a truth table, find a  logic circuit able to reproduce this truth table.

Obviously, this requires a methodology. Minterm and sum-of-products is mean to realize that. Maxterms and product-of-sums is another one. In either case, you get an algebraic representation of your truth table and you can either implement it directly or try to apply standard theorems of boolean algebra to find an equivalent, but simpler, representation.

But these are not the only tools. For instance, with Karnaugh maps, you rewrite your truth table with some rules and you can simultaneously find an algebraic representation and reduce its complexity, and it does not consider minterms. Its main drawback is that it becomes unworkable if the number of inputs rises and it cannot be considered as a general way to solve the problem of logic design.

It happens that minterms (or maxterms) do not have this drawback, and can be used to solve any problem. We get a trut table and we can directly convert it in an equation with ands, ors and nots. Indeed minterms are somehow simpler to human beings than maxterms, but it is just a matter of taste or of a reduced number of parenthesis, they are actually equivalent.

> But I fail to understand why we always complement the 0s to express them as 1. Is it assumed that the inputs X, Y and Z will always be 1?

Assume that we have a truth table, with only a given output at 1. For instance, as line 3 of your table. It means that when x=0, y=1 and z=0 , the output will be zero. So, can I express that in boolean logic? With the SOP methodology, we say that *we want a solution for this problem that is an "and" of entries or of their complement*. And obviously the solution is "x must be false and y must be true and z must be false" or "(not x) must be true and y must be true and (not z) must be true", hence the minterm /x.y./z. So complementing when we have a 0 and leaving unchanged when we have a 1 is way to find the equation that will be true when xyz=010

If I have another table with only one output at 1 (for instance line 8 of your table), we can find similarly that I can implement this TT with x.y.z.

Now if I have a TT with 2 lines at 1, one can use the property of OR gates and do the OR of the previous circuits. when the output of the first one is 1, it will force this behavior and ditto for the second. And we directly get the solution for your table /xy/z+xyz

This can be extended to any number of ones in the TT and gives a systematic way to find an equation equivalent to a truth table.

So just think of minterms and maxterms as a *tool* to translate a TT into equations. What is important is the truth table (that describes the *behaviour* of what you want to do) and the equations (that give you a way to *realize* it).